# Im trying to show images that i uploaded to the database using longblob and PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, blob

Im trying to show images that i uploaded to the database using longblob and PDO but i always get a black screen with a small white square in the center.
This is the code:

```
<?php
    include('snippets/startDB.php');
    include('snippets/Session.php');
    
    $PicNum = $_GET["PicNum"]; echo($PicNum);
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT imagem FROM aluno WHERE id= ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($PicNum));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();


    Header( 'Content-type: image/gif');
     echo $row['imagem'];
?>
```

I think the save file is working correctly because a file appears in the database when i upload the image.
My save file:

```
<?php

$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];
include('snippets/startDB.php');
include('snippets/Session.php');

if($imagem != NULL) {
    $nomeFinal = time().'.jpg';
    if (move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $nomeFinal)) {
        $tamanhoImg = filesize($nomeFinal);

        $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($nomeFinal, "r"), $tamanhoImg));

        if($_SESSION['tipo']== 'Aluno'){
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE aluno SET imagem = ? WHERE id = ?');
            
            $stmt->execute(array($mysqlImg, $_SESSION["id"]));
            
        }else if($_SESSION['tipo']== 'Professor'){
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE professor SET imagem = ? WHERE id = ?') ;
            
            $stmt->execute(array($mysqlImg, $_SESSION["id"])) ;

        }
        
         header("location:perfil_aluno.php");
    }
}
else {
    echo"Erro!";
}

?>
```

Comment: are you sure the image is gif (not jpeg and png) ?

Comment: please also change `$PicNum = $_GET["PicNum"]; echo($PicNum);` to `$PicNum = $_GET["PicNum"]; ` to see the effect

Comment: removed the echo and changed from gif to png and also tries with jpg did not work. the file is getting stored on the database but is also appearing in the local folder of the webpage what i think is not suposed to do.

Comment: "also appearing in the local folder of the webpage what i think is not suposed to do" - That's exactly what `move_uploaded_file()` does. You also apply `addslashes()` to a binary file—in the best scenario it'll accomplish anything, in the worst case it'll break the picture.

Comment: yes i saw that i will probably load the images form the directory instead of sendind it to the database